# integrals calculation got wrong with the extra 2

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

Given $$ f(x, y) = \begin{cases} 
2e^{-(x+2y)}, & x>0, y>0 \\
0, &otherwise
\end{cases}$$

For $ D: 0 <x \le 1, 0 <y \le2$, I'm trying to calculate this
$$ \iint_D f(x,y) \, dxdy $$
$$ = \int_0^1\left[((1-e^{-2y})(1-e^{-x}))'\bigg|_0^2\right]dx = \int_0^1\left[-(1-e^{-x})(-2y)'e^{-2y}\bigg|_0^2\right]dx $$
$$ = \int_0^1 2(1-e^{-x})(e^{-4}-1)\, dx = (-2(e^{-4}-1)e^{-x})'\bigg|_0^1 = 2(e^{-4}-1)e^{-x}\bigg|_0^1 $$
$$ = 2(e^{-4}-1)(e^{-1} -1) = 2(1-e^{-4})(1-e^{-1})$$

There must be something wrong with my calculation, but I can't find where it is.

Comment: I don't understand what you're doing. The integral is a number, the given second order partial derivative is a non-constant function.

Comment: I've updated my question. Hopefully, now it is clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have absolutely no idea what you are doing but here is the answer

$$ \int_0^2 \int_0^1 2e^{-(x+2y)} \,dx\,dy = \int_0^1e^{-x}\,dx \int_0^2 2e^{-2y}\,dy \\
= \big[ -e^{-x} \big]_0^1 \big[ -e^{-2y} \big]_0^2 = (1 - e^{-1})(1 - e^{-4}) $$

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you do not distinguish well between integras and derivatives.

**Derivative**
$$ \frac{\partial F(x,y)}{\partial x}=(1-e^{-2y})e^{-x} $$
$$ \frac{\partial^2 F(x,y)}{\partial x \partial y}=2e^{-2y}e^{-x}. $$
**Integral**
$$ \int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{2}F(x,y)dy dx=\int_{0}^{1}(1-e^{-x})(y+\frac{1}{2}e^{-2y})\bigl|_{0}^{2}dx=$$
$$=(x+e^{-x})\bigl|_{0}^{1}(y+\frac{1}{2}e^{-2y})\bigl|_{0}^{2}=e^{-1}(\frac{3}{2}+\frac{1}{2}e^{-4}).$$

Answer (score 0):

$\partial^2 F(x,y) \over \partial x \partial y$$ = \int_0^1 \int_0^2F(x,y)dydx$
 is false $f(1,2)=\int_0^1\int_0^2$$\partial^2f(x,y)dxdyover \partial x\partial y$$ is true